# What's the right definition of peewee model while mapping from json file?

Tags: json, peewee

Hi stack overflow community! This is my first question here, but I tried to find an answer beforehand. Right now I am working on loading data from json file [like so](https://randomuser.me/) (I actually have a json file named `persons.json`, not API) with the use of `peewee` to SQLite DB. As you can see, the json file has multiple nested dicts. My `peewee` model is as follows:

```
import json
import sqlite3
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('persons.sqlite3')

class Person(Model):
    gender = CharField()
    name = CharField()
    location = CharField()
    email = CharField()
    login = CharField()
    dob = CharField()
    registered = CharField()
    phone = CharField()
    cell = CharField()
    id_ = CharField()
    picture = CharField()
    nat = CharField()
    count_dob = IntegerField()
```

And this is how I load all the data from json file to SQLite DB:

```
db.connect()

db.create_tables([Person])

with open('persons.json', encoding='utf8') as persons:
    persons_data = json.load(persons)


for person in persons_data['results']:
    p = Person(gender=person['gender'], name=person['name'], location=person['location'], email=person['email'], 
                login=person['login'], dob=person['dob'], registered=person['registered'], phone=person['phone'],
                cell=person['cell'], id_=person['id'], picture=person['picture'], nat=person['nat'])
```

My question is, do you think the variables in my model are correctly defined (basically every single one of them as a CharField) ? The thing is, later whenever I query the DB and I need to access some of these nested dictionaries, they are actually a string, which I can convert with the use of `ast.literal_eval` back to dict, but I don't think it looks nice. I thought of a solution - for all the 'dictionary type' variables in my model ('location', 'dob' etc), instead of using `CharField()` I could probably use `JSONField()` - not sure how to do that though. Could you please advise on that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relational databases do not support "nesting". It's foundational. Anything that is nested should probably be in a separate table or in its own column as a flat/scalar value.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization